# Legend color is missing

Tags: pandas, graph, plotly, visualization, treemap

I am trying to plot using a treemap in plotly using the code:

```
   fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant(df ['N']), df ['M']],values=df ['J'],color=df ['J'],color_continuous_scale = "RdBu")
   fig.show()
```

However, the treemap doesn't show the level score colors (please see the image below)

[image]

I already used `pd.to_numeric()`but still the same result.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that this only happens when I use "Save plot as" but if I use "fig.write_image()" the legend color level appears in jpeg. So I advise to directly use fig.write_image instead of saving it to an html image.